# from cm³ to a cylindrical shape how to convert?

Tags: geometry

Given that silver has a density of **10.49 g/cm³**, what's the way to convert it to cylindrical shape? (meaning what's the density of silver in a cylindrical shape rather than in **cm³**).

For example, if I want to know what **thickness** of silver I'll get in a cylindrical shape of which I cast inside **0.5g** of silver, if the cylinder shape is **5mm** in diameter. By the end of this process I should get a new round metal with a cylindrical shape from the silver I cast into the other cylinder.

What's the best / easiest way to find the height / thickness of the new cylindrical shape in this case? (I'm not asking for the solution but the way that will help me to find familiar problems in future).

Comment: What do you mean by "a round shape"? A cylinder, like a coin? A sphere?

Comment: @kccu yes, to a cylindrical shape. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know that the volume of a cylinder of radius $r$ and height $h$ is $\pi r^2h$?

Comment: Divide the mass by the density to obtain a volume. The volume is a base area times the height, so you need to know area of the cylinder's base to calculate the height (thickness).

Comment: Is this a hollow cylinder like a ring? or a straw? or a solid cylinder?  Do you want long and thin or short and fat?  There is too little information here to give an answer.

Comment: Let's think about a coin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area of a cylinder is $2\pi r^2$ for the ends and $2\pi rh$ for the tube section.  If you are going to cover the whole cylinder including the ends you add these together.

$0.5 g$ of silver has a volume of $\frac {0.5}{10.49}=0.05 $cm$^3$ where I rounded to one place to match the input.  Divide this volume by the area to get the thickness.  You gave the diameter but not the height of the cylinder so I can't calculate the thickness.

With the edit, it appears you are making a solid cylinder of diameter $0.5$ cm or a radius of $0.25$cm.  It has an area of $\pi 0.25^2=0.2$ cm$^2$.  The thickness is then $\frac {0.05}{0.2}=0.25$ cm.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just calculated the way you showed. Could it be the accurate thickness is 0.25464790895? Just to confirm that I understood it properly)

Comment: It could well be.  As I was calculating to about one place (but didn't round the last) I didn't use a calculator.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that the volume for a (circular) cylinder is given by

$$V= \pi R^2h$$

then, fixed the radius $R$ $(cm)$, we can find the height by

$$h=\frac{V}{\pi R^2}\, (cm)$$

with

$$V=\frac{M}{\rho} \, (cm^3)$$

where $M$ is the mass $(g)$ and $\rho$ is the density $(g/cm^3)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your way and I got different results from the method of the other comment: 0.000994718394 (this is what I got by your method) while by the other comment the result is: 0.25cm. Probably I didn't understand something here. What's wrong in my way? Maybe the second comment is wrong? I have no way to know it.

Comment: @Math-Enthusiast You are welcome! Bye

Comment: I edited my comment

Comment: @Math-Enthusiast I've interpreted your question in a different way from the other one. I thought you were looking for a solid cylinder with an assigned diameter and you were interested in the height.

Comment: I see. Sorry about that. Probably it's because of my ability to express myself in a language that I'm not a native to. Anyway, thank you very much for your elucidation.

Comment: You are welcome! I’ll add a complete calculation tomorrow! Bye